# jquery - dblclick on child also triggers dblclick event on parent

Tags: jquery, ondblclick

I have this odd problem where i have an UL with some LI elements in it.. I have bound a dblclick() event to both the UL and the LI, and when I dblclick the LI element, both the LI event and the UL event is triggered.. is there a way to avoid this?

This is my code:

```
    $("ul").dblclick(function () {
        alert("ul clicked");
    });

    $("li").dblclick(function () {
        alert("li clicked");
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

The `dblclick` event *bubbles* up the DOM tree, and ancestor elements are also notified. To prevent the event from bubbling, you need to [stop propagation of the event](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/):

```
$("li").dblclick(function (e) {
    alert("li clicked");
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/HkUQ4/**